# Why am I getting this context and database error?

Tags: android, database, listview

> I am trying to...

create a simple listview that can be populated with data from an sqldatabase. The database works, I've seen it work with other code. The XML is fine and I really don't need to share it. When it comes to the XML, there is two buttons in the main activity: new and show. New sends you to the next activity to add to the list. Show will add data to the listview. That's all for the main activity. The other activity called NewEntry has a cancel button and a save button. It also has three editviews to help you add data.

> **Problems:**

Right now it doesn't even compile without errors. The two errors are listed below in the main activity. If I comment out those two errors, I can get the application to run. when I open a new activity and try to save it, it crashes. They have to do with Context. I only sort of understand what Context does besides the fact that it is in everything.

> **This error has been solved see the bottom**
>   The two compiler errors are in this code here. This is the main activity.
>   There are no other compiler errors, just logical ones.
>   I have pointed them out in the comments
>   ""DATA BASE MANAGER CANNOT BE APPLIED TO LISTENER""
>   "CANNOT RESOLVE CONSTRUCTOR"

Also any explanations of Context will be appreciated.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class Main extends Activity {
    private DatabaseManager mydManager;
    private ListView productRec;
    ArrayList<String> tableContent;
    private LinearLayout addLayout;
    ArrayList<String> arrayAdpt;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        productRec=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);               
        Button newButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_button);
        Button showButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_button);
        Button newButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_button);

        newButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
            public void onClick(View n) {
               Intent x = new Intent(Main.this.getApplicationContext(), NewEntry.class);
               startActivity(x);

            }
        });


        showButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            //Want this to launch new intent
            public void onClick(View s) {    
               mydManager = new DatabaseManager(this); // <ERROR: 
               mydManager.openReadable();               //"DATA BASE MANAGER CANNOT BE APPLIED TO LISTENER"     
               tableContent = mydManager.retrieveRows();                
               productRec = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);       
               mydManager.retrieveRows();  //ERROR:
               ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdpt=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tableContent);    //ERROR:CANNOT RESOLVE CONSTRUCTOR
               productRec.setAdapter(arrayAdpt);
               productRec.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               mydManager.close();

            }
        });


    }

}
```

> This is the NewEntry java class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class NewEntry extends Activity {
    //   public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private EditText titleView;
    private EditText authorView;
    private EditText priceView;
    private Button doneButton;
    private Button cancelButton;
    private DatabaseManager mydManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit);

        titleView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title_input);
        authorView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.author_input);
        priceView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.price_input);
        doneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.done_button);
        cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);

        Intent i = this.getIntent();


//rec inserted, its a boolean in the other one
        doneButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mydManager = new DatabaseManager(NewEntry.this);
                mydManager.addRow(Integer.parseInt(titleView.getText().toString()), authorView.getText().toString(),
                        Float.parseFloat(priceView.getText().toString()));            ///sending in back to database
                // InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                // imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(priceView.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                mydManager.close();
                titleView.setText("");
                authorView.setText("");                //SOMETHING TO DO WITH DATA? maybe its blanking it out
                priceView.setText("");

                finish();
            }
        });
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

> ```
> This is the database:
> ```

```
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DatabaseManager {
    public static final String DB_NAME = "shopping";
    public static final String DB_TABLE = "products";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE + " (code INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, product_name TEXT, date FLOAT);";
    private SQLHelper helper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private Context context;

    public DatabaseManager(Context c){
        this.context = c;
        helper=new SQLHelper(c);
        this.db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public DatabaseManager openReadable() throws android.database.SQLException {
        helper=new SQLHelper(context);
        db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    public void close(){
        helper.close();
    }
    public boolean addRow(int t, String a, float p){
        ContentValues newProduct = new ContentValues();
        newProduct.put("title", t);
        newProduct.put("author", a);
        newProduct.put("price", p);
        try{db.insertOrThrow(DB_TABLE, null, newProduct);}
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error in inserting rows ", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        db.close();
        return true;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> retrieveRows(){    ///Retrieves edit
        ArrayList<String> productRows=new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] columns = new String[]{"title", "author", "price"};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(DB_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
            productRows.add(Integer.toString(cursor.getInt(0)) + ", "+cursor.getString(1)+", "+Float.toString(cursor.getFloat(2)));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return productRows;
    }


    public class SQLHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public SQLHelper(Context c){
            super(c, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w("Products table","Upgrading database i.e. dropping table and recreating it");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DB_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
}
```

Error when trying to retrieve rows:

```
04-11 22:08:25.552  21767-21767/com.example.alex.checkbox W/dalvikvm? threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41e7cda0)
04-11 22:08:25.572  21767-21767/com.example.alex.checkbox E/AndroidRuntime? FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.alex.checkbox, PID: 21767
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: title (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT title, author, price FROM products
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1113)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:690)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1448)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1295)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1166)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1334)
            at com.example.alex.favoritebooks.DatabaseManager.retrieveRows(DatabaseManager.java:56)
            at com.example.alex.favoritebooks.Main$2.onClick(Main.java:45)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4654)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19438)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `newButton.setOnClickListener(...)` code you are using the application `Context` when creating your `Intent`. Don't do that - instead use the `Activity` `Context`...

```
newButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View n) {
        // Simply use Main.this on the next line...
        Intent x = new Intent(Main.this, NewEntry.class);
        startActivity(x);
    }
});
```

In your `showButton.setOnClickListener(...)` code you are passing a reference to the `OnClickListener` object to the constructor of your DatabaseManager and also when creating your ArrayAdapter...

```
showButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View s) {
        mydManager = new DatabaseManager(this); //Here is the error

        ...

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdpt=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tableContent);

        ...
    }
});
```

The `this` keyword refers to the current instance of any object which uses it - in this case, `this` refers to the `OnClickListener` which is not a `Context`. Also, as an aside, you're declaring a new `ArrayAdapter` variable in your `OnClickListener` code instead of using the one declared in the `Activity`. Change the code as follows...

```
showButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View s) {
        mydManager = new DatabaseManager(Main.this);

        ...

        arrayAdpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Main.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tableContent);

        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Main.this for the ArrayAdapter will then reference the array adapter initialized at the top. Main.this will reference itself for the intent? But why?

Comment: I don't really understand your comment above. Using `Main.this` will always  be a reference to the Main `Activity`. As an `Activity` indirectly extends `Context`, then an `Activity` *IS* a `Context`. When you declare an inline/anonymous class (such as the `new OnClickListener() {...}` code), you're inside that class code therefore `this` would refer to the `OnClickListener`.

Comment: The error noted is solved and I will give you this answer. I believe it is saving now but when I come to show the data I get an error. I am now getting an error at " tableContent = mydManager.retrieveRows();" in Main.java and "Cursor cursor = db.query(DB_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null); " in the Database file.

Comment: So what's the error? It almost certainly doesn't have anything to do with your original `Context` problem.

Comment: "FATAL EXCEPTION: main" or uncaught exception.

Comment: That doesn't explain anything - edit your question and post the full stacktrace from logcat

Comment: Edited. It is crashing when trying to retrieve rows. My first thought is that it would be a mismatch of strings and integers but it isn't.

Comment: Look at your `private static final String CREATE_TABLE` string. You create a table with columns called 'code', 'product_name' and 'date' but your query is trying to retrieve columns called 'title', 'author' and 'price'.